# Descendant state in same tab?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my Ionic app, I have a "Home" tab which displays a list of people. Each of these list items have two buttons, one for contacting them and one for showing information about them.

What I wish to accomplish is that each button would take the user to that particular person's contact or info page, *in the same tab* (ie. the home tab is still highlighted/selected, and the user can swipe left-to-right to return to the home page).

What is the best possible way of doing this?

Below are the relevant snippets of my current code.

**app.js**

```
.state('tab.home', {
  url: '/home',
  views: {
    'tab-home': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    },
    // 'rep-contact': {
    //   templateUrl: 'templates/rep-contact.html',
    //   controller: 'RepContactCtrl'
    // }, 'rep-info': {
    //   templateUrl: 'templates/rep-info.html',
    //   controller: 'RepInfoCtrl'
    // }
  }
})

 ...

.state('rep-contact', {
  url: '/contact',
  // parent: 'tab.home',
  templateUrl: 'templates/rep-contact.html',
  controller: 'RepContactCtrl',
  params: {
    name: null
  }
})
```

**controllers.js**

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicViewSwitcher) {

...

  $scope.goToContactPage = function(name) {
    $ionicViewSwitcher.nextDirection('forward');
    $state.go('rep-contact', { name: name });
  };
})
```

**tab-home.html list item button (contact button only)**

```
<button class="button button-balanced icon ion-ios-telephone button-contact float-right" ng-click="goToContactPage(rep.name)"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    .state('tab.rep-contact', {
      url: '/contact',
      views: {
        'tab-home': {
           templateUrl: 'templates/rep-contact.html',
           controller: 'RepContactCtrl'
        },
      }
    })
```